# Training loss fluctuates but validation loss is nearly constant

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python

I am training a network ESNet in Pytorch to predict vanishing point as per VPGNet ICCV 2017 paper. I am using SGD with 0.1 learning rate and ReducedLR scheduler with patience = 5.

My loss curve is something like this which I am not able to interpret.[image]

Any idea what is happening?

Visually the network predicts nearly the same point in almost all the validation images.

PS: Y axis is loss and X is the epoch. The network is trained for 150 epochs.

Comment: Could you explain what the axes are? I assume $y$ axis is value of loss function but $x = ?$

Comment: Yeah sorry, Y is loss and X is epoch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visually the network predicts nearly the same point in almost all the
> validation images.

Unless your validation set is full of very similar images, this is a sign of underfitting. Also the stability in the validation loss from the start indicates that the network not learning. There are fluctuations in the training curve, but I'd say they are more or less around the same values. Interestingly there are larger fluctuations in the training loss, but the problem with underfitting is more pressing.

Plotting the learning rate by epochs would be useful to see the effect of `patience` hyperparameter.